# How to expose XCTestCases to external test bundles?

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest, dependency-inversion

I have a framework `Whiteboard` that encapsulates my business logic. I'm trying to keep my dependencies inverted and decoupled, so since `Whiteboard` depends on a repository, it declares a protocol `WhiteboardRepository`, and it expects clients that link against `Whiteboard` to supply an implementation of `WhiteboardRepository`.

You can see this in the screen shot below. Note also the `WhiteboardTests` group, which includes a `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` class along with a `WhiteboardRepositoryFake` and its own test subclass.

[image]

To ensure that implementations of `WhiteboardRepository` behave as expected, the `WhiteboardTests` test bundle defines a `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` subclass of `XCTestCase`:

```
class WhiteboardRepositoryTests: XCTestCase {
  var repo: WhiteboardRepository?

  override func setUp() {
    if let repo = repo {
      // test setup here
    }
  }

  // test cases here

}
```

In order for a client of `Whiteboard` to test its implementation of `WhiteboardRepository`, the test class for the implementation subclasses the `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` and supplies an instance of the implementation to the test subclass, which then uses that instance when running the tests.

For example, here's what `WhiteboardRepositoryFakeTests` looks like:

```
class WhiteboardRepositoryFakeTests: WhiteboardRepositoryTests {
    override func setUp() {
        repo = WhiteboardRepositoryFake()
        super.setUp()
    }

    // the test classes run, using the instance of WhiteboardRepositoryFake()
}
```

This works fine, of course, since `WhiteboardRepositoryFakeTests` is in the `WhiteboardTests` bundle, so `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` is exposed to `WhiteboardRepositoryFakeTests`.

The problem is: apps that link against `Whiteboard` will need to create their own subclass of `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` to test their own implementation, but because they don't have access to the `WhiteboardTests` test bundle, they're not aware of the `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` class and so can't subclass it.

I've got multiple clients consuming `Whiteboard`, so I can't simply copy the `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` class into each client—and nor would I want to, since it's the responsibility of `Whiteboard` to define `WhiteboardRepository`'s behavior, so `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` should live in `Whiteboard`'s test bundle. In an ideal world, I'd be able to link or inject `Whiteboard`'s test bundle into a client's test bundle so that `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` is exposed to the client's tests, but I don't see how I can do this.

Is there any way around this obstacle? How can I expose `WhiteboardRepositoryTests` to tests within a client test bundle so that the client can make sure its implementation of `WhiteboardRepository` behaves as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that the WhiteboardTests target is likely a test target and does not actually build a linkable framework. This prevents us from building another target (your client tests) that imports and subclass from it. For example, you'll notice that a test target lacks the normal {TARGET_NAME}.h header file that is used to export symbols from the framework. What we need is a target that builds a framework but links with XCTest. Client projects' test targets will link with this framework to import and subclass the XCTestCase classes it provides. So what to do:

1. Create a framework building target in your Whiteboard project by clicking the project file then Editor > Add Target. Let's call this WhiteboardAbstractTests for now. This target will link with XCTest and build a framework to supply the superclasses that you want your client projects' tests to subclass.
2. Now, to link with XCTest is a bit weird because they don't make it readily available in Xcode anymore. However, you can still find the XCTest framework at `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework` and drag this into the WhiteboardAbstractTests target folder in Xcode.
3. From here, you should be able to define XCTestCase subclasses in WhiteboardAbstractTests that will be built into the WhiteboardAbstractTests.framework.
4. In your client project, I assume that the Whiteboard xcodeproj is nested in some way, either by Cocoapods, Carthage, or git submodule. Find the Whiteboard xcodeproj file and drag it into the client project test target in Xcode.
5. Select the client project file in Xcode and go to Build Phases. Under Target dependencies, click the plus button and you should see various build targets from Whiteboard. Select WhiteboardAbstractTests. This will make sure Xcode builds the abstract tests before building your clients tests.
6. Also in Build Phases, under Link Binary With Libraries, select WhiteboardAbstractTests to make sure that our test target links with and can import classes from the abstract tests provided by Whiteboard.

From here you should be able to run the tests in your client project which will build WhiteboardAbstractTests, link your client tests with it, and run your client tests which subclass the abstract tests. I've quickly tested it out but let me know if you have trouble.

P.S. I like your architectural style. Somewhere Martin Fowler sheds a tear of joy.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but when I tried it, I got `Cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'`. When I try adding `#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>` to the bridging header, the "load module" error goes away, but I get an `'XCTest/XCTest.h' file not found` error in the bridging header, which is especially confusing as `XCTest.h` is right there in the framework I dragged in.

Comment: Hang on, I think maybe I got it—the first part at least. I had to literally copy the `XCTest` framework into my project and add to the framework search paths to point directly to it on disk. Then I had to link the Whiteboard framework to `WhiteboardContractTests`, and finally, I had to give the test file target membership to the `WhiteboardTests` test bundle. I'll go try making the client-side work now.

Comment: Ah yeah I wasn't totally clear about XCTest but I think you've got the idea.

Comment: Rather than copying XCTest.framework around, instead add `${PLATFORM_DIR}/Developer/Library/Frameworks` to the "Framework Search Paths" build setting of the test framework target. This should allow you to import XCTest without any further shenanigans.