# Error when running UI Test w external test bundle in XCode on Device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

my testkit consits of two .swift files, which are placed in two different modules.
The one which is running the tests, imports the other .swift file as a cocoatouch framework and "@testable import". (thanks to [How to expose XCTestCases to external test bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277720/how-to-expose-xctestcases-to-external-test-bundles)).

When i'm running the tests in the XCode simulator, everything seems to work out fine.
However, if i want to run it on the device, i get the following error:

```
2017-02-27 16:13:18.555859 XCTRunner[17456:2201607] Running tests...
2017-02-27 16:13:18.595556 XCTRunner[17456:2201607] The bundle “EBoxUITest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2017-02-27 16:13:18.595703 XCTRunner[17456:2201607] (dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5F467D62-3711-46BF-9593-876C29A69B20/EBoxUITest-Runner.app/PlugIns/EBoxUITest.xctest/EBoxUITest): Library not loaded: @rpath/DCFrontendTests.framework/DCFrontendTests
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5F467D62-3711-46BF-9593-876C29A69B20/EBoxUITest-Runner.app/PlugIns/EBoxUITest.xctest/EBoxUITest
  Reason: image not found)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a debug build that's installed on the device?

Comment: yes, i cleaned the app (as well as the testbundle) from the device before. nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

you should set UITest Target Build Phases Link Binary With Libraries